# How to get HTTP POST parameters in exact order in Django?

Tags: python, django, rest, paypal

I am trying to get the POST data parameters in the exact order they are received in Django.

I have this in my `views.py`:

```
@require_POST
@csrf_exempt
def paypal_ipn_listener(request):
    print request.POST
    print request.body
```

The data in `request.POST` is in `QueryDict` which is unordered, thus doesn't suit my needs.

Trying to access `request.body` throws an exception:

```
RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

I think this exception happens because of my `@require_POST`  or `@csrf_exempt` decorators which perhaps call some middleware which reads POST data stream.

Anyway my question is how do I get HTTP request POST data in exact order?

I need to keep the order to satisfy [PayPal IPN implementation requirements](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/).

** UPDATE **

I ended up manually parsing `request.body` since there is no better solution.

Comment: You get that error because you accessed `request.POST` *first*. If you removed that line, you wouldn't get the error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Good idea, but I removed the first print and I still get the same error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman After further testing that seems to be the case. Post as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you delete @require_POST and do something like this?:

```
from django.http import Http404

@csrf_exempt
def paypal_ipn_listener(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('some error')
    print request.body
```